# Анализ DOM сайта

Tags: парсер

Как проанализировать некоторый сайт полностью: с заголовками, ценами, описанием и желательно это разбить по категориям.

Пробовал Datacol, а теперь хочется понять как это реализовать с помощью PHP.

От знающих требуется хотя бы пример.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на примере библиотеки
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
```